# SchemaCrawler mysql json output does not include parameter names

Tags: mysql, json, schemacrawler

I am testing `SchemaCrawler` in command line mode, but I'm unable to get the stored procedure parameter names in the json output. The parameter names are visible in the html output, but do not appear in the json for the same settings.

Command :
`./sc.sh -infolevel=maximum -server=mysql -c=schema -database=PHYSICS -outputformat=json -outputfile=shema.json`

Comment: This is a bug. I will fix it in the next release, and post an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give an estimate of when will be the next release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of SchemaCrawler. Please download and use SchemaCrawler 12.05.02 or better.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)